# How to write a power automate(flow) to check if every department has uploaded a report file for every day?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, power-automate, microsoft-flow

I have a document library with the department as a column. Every day, each department upload a file and I want a consolidated email to check which department has not uploaded the file.

I have about 20 departments and manually checking them every day is taking huge time.

How to achieve this, any high-level steps?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with power automate like:

1. Use **Scheduled flow**
2. Retrieve SharePoint document library items for the current day (maybe using Send HTTP request to SharePoint action & filter query)
3. Check the department column in loop
4. Send consolidated email as per your requirements using outlook/mail connector

This will require some complex logic for sure.

---

Instead of building power automate flow, try using SharePoint out of the box **Alert me** feature which sends daily report of changes in list/library once in a day at specified time.

[image]

Check more information at: [Create an alert to get notified when a file or folder changes in SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-an-alert-to-get-notified-when-a-file-or-folder-changes-in-sharepoint-e5a79e7b-a146-46da-a9ef-d65409ba8918)